# How To change "Feature" to open from App actions for OPEN_FEATURE?

Tags: android, json, voice-recognition, voice, app-actions

This is the actions.xml that I have:

```
<actions>
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT">
    <parameter name="account.name">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="AccountEntitySet" />
    </parameter>
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.xelion.com/account{?accountType}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="account.name"
            urlParameter="accountType" />
    </fulfillment>
</action>

<action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
    <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
    </parameter>
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.xelion.com/open{?featureName}">
        <parameter-mapping
            entityMatchRequired="true"
            intentParameter="feature"
            urlParameter="featureName" />
    </fulfillment>
</action>


<entity-set entitySetId="EntitySet">

    <!-- For each entity you can specify the name, alternate names and the identifier -->
    <!-- The identifier is the value that will be added to the action uri. -->
    <!-- For our sample we map the supported entities with the class FitActivity.Type  -->
    <entity
        name="start"
        identifier="START" />
    <entity
        name="stop"
        identifier="STOP" />

</entity-set>
<entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
    <entity
        name="call"
        alternateName="@array/callSynopsis"
        identifier="CALL" />
    <entity
        name="history"
        identifier="HISTORY" />
</entity-set>
<entity-set entitySetId="AccountEntitySet">
    <entity
        name="utility"
        identifier="UTILITY" />
    <entity
        name="sales"
        identifier="SALES" />
</entity-set>

</actions>
```

Now if I try: "Get Dialler Xelion Account" this will trigger the GET_ACCOUNT .

If I try "Open HISTORY on Dialler Xelion" It also recognises the feature and opens the app.

But it does not work for: "Open Call on Dialler Xelion" 
As you can see I have it in the FeatureEntitySet, so what might be the issue?

Also in the App Actions Test Tool v3.0.0 if I select OPEN_APP_FEATURE it only shows: "History" I can modify it, but if I update it will remain the same. Please help

[image]

Also I added a AccountEntitySet for the getAccount, but that also does not show. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by now. Also, the JSON included is just a sample not meant to be updated with your any custom value.

A few suggestions to continue troubleshooting this issue:

1. **Validate SLICE_AUTHORITY in three places** Make sure SLICE_AUTHORITY in the SliceProvider extended class matches `android:authorities` in AndroidManifest.xml file, and actions.xml declaration.
2. **Try a fresh sample.** If none of these steps work. Try the [Fitness Android sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin) and work backward to compare and identify gaps in your app.

Please let me know if SLICE_AUTHORITY(#2) ends up being the issue here.

Comment: The Fitness Android Sample doesn't seem to have any examples of how to implement an "OPEN_APP_FEATURE" action type, do you know about another project that might have some? I think the generic actions, such as open_app and get_thing are the ones that seem to have issues. I'm currently trying to do the same as rosu alin, and it all works with "history" feature, which seems to be there by default, but I can't seem to be able of defining my own feature names because whenever I try to invoke them, I only get a regular Google search.

Comment: Sure. For OPEN_APP_FEATURE and GET_THING BIIs, try this sample. https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-common-biis-kotlin